# Error with Web Service SOAP (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, http-status-code-405, servlet-listeners

i have this web service:

```
@WebService
public interface IRobotWhatsappService {

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "resultRobotWhatsapp")
public ResultRobotWhatsapp login (@WebParam(name = "correoPersonaQueEscanea") String correoPersonaQueEscanea);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "resultRobotWhatsapp")
public ResultRobotWhatsapp leer  (@WebParam(name = "nombreContactoParaLeer") String nombreContactoParaLeer,
                                  @WebParam(name = "identificadorSesion") String identificadorSesion);

@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "resultRobotWhatsapp")
public ResultRobotWhatsapp enviar(@WebParam(name = 
"nombreContactoDestinatario") String nombreContactoDestinatario,
                                  @WebParam(name = "mensaje")String mensaje,
                                  @WebParam(name = "identificadorSesion") 
                                  String identificadorSesion);
}
```

And i have the most basic implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.test.application.robot.ws.IRobotWhatsappService")
public class RobotWhatsappService implements IRobotWhatsappService{

@Override
public ResultRobotWhatsapp login(String correoPersonaQueEscanea) {
    ResultRobotWhatsapp resultRobotWhatsapp =new ResultRobotWhatsapp(); 
    resultRobotWhatsapp.setMessage("Login");
    return resultRobotWhatsapp;
}

@Override
public ResultRobotWhatsapp leer(String nombreContactoParaLeer, String identificadorSesion) {
    ResultRobotWhatsapp resultRobotWhatsapp =new ResultRobotWhatsapp();
    resultRobotWhatsapp.setMessage("Leer");
    return resultRobotWhatsapp;
}

@Override
public ResultRobotWhatsapp enviar(String nombreContactoDestinatario, String mensaje, String identificadorSesion) {
    ResultRobotWhatsapp resultRobotWhatsapp =new ResultRobotWhatsapp();
    resultRobotWhatsapp.setMessage("Enviar");
    return resultRobotWhatsapp;
}

}
```

And  in my web.xml i haver this configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>     
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soap/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My WS shows the methods correctly but when i do a request i am getting the jsp for 405 status error.
In my securityContext.xml i have the exception:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/RobotWhatsapp**" access="permitAll" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/soap/**" access="permitAll" />
```

And in my application context xml i have the bean and endpoint:

```
<bean id="robotWhatsappImplBean" class="com.konecta.application.robot.ws.RobotWhatsappService" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="robotWhatsappImpl" implementor="#robotWhatsappImplBean" address="/RobotWhatsapp" />
```

Do you have any idea about the problem?

This is an example with soapui:

[image]

All that from here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using springSecurityFilterChain with CSRF protection. That means i have to send a token when i do the request. 
Everything was well, just i needed add this in my Security Context:

```
<sec:csrf disabled="true" />
```

If you have that configuration in a .java file, you could do this:

```
.and().csrf().disable();
```

In your filters